# Under what conditions is this product greater than 1?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following product:
$$
\frac{x^T(X^TX)^{-1}x}{x^Tx}
$$

Where x $\in$ R$^{N}$ and X $\in$ R$^{M\times N}$. In my application, $X$ is a [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix) for linear regression. $x$ is a vector of inputs. **Under what conditions is this product greater than $\frac{1}{x^Tx}$?**

I few ideas:

- This looks like Rayleigh quotient
- $X^TX$ is positive semi-definite
- See the "Special case of covariance matrices" [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)
- I think $(X^TX)^{-1}$ yields a Hermatian matrix

Comment: You might want to normalize w.r.t. $x$

Comment: Just so I understand, if I do this then should I make the lower bound 1/$x^Tx$?

Comment: At the end of the day, if you don't normalize, $1/x^Tx$ will appear in the condition that you are looking for, so maybe my comment is redundant... But if you don't normalize $x$ and standardize $X$, I'm fairly certain that your conjecture won't hold. Due to continuity $B(x,X) = |x^T (X^TX)^{-1}x| \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ (for fixed $X$) or as $X_{i,j} \to \infty$ for all $i,j$ (for fixed $x$).

Comment: As a matter of fact the continuity is not important, sorry. The important take is that the limit shows that the expression you described can become arbitrarily small.

Comment: Very good observations! I will edit my question to focus on the conditions where the product is greater than 1.

Comment: I think you require as @MarkoKarbevski has pointed out that something like $\|x\|_2 = 1$. In that case, wouldn't a sufficient requirement be that the minimum eigenvalue of $(X^T X)^{-1} \ge 1$?

Comment: Alright, I think normalizing has helped. But I think that means the minimum eigenvector of $(X^TX)^{-1} \ge 1/(x^Tx)$

Comment: Do you expect that the inverse of the positive semi definite matrix exists?